# A mock management system?

Tags: c#, java, .net, unit-testing, mocking

I'm just curious if there is any software, that could help me with mock management and creation - I prefer Java and .net but I'll be happy to see it for any other languages.

My imagination could be something like this:

A simple wizard that can look into class, generate simple Excel style editor where you can add new mock with different values set, default values etc...

Easy access to this mock via say dot notation and index for example:

```
MockRepository.getMock => platform.domain.person[person_name="John"]
```

So, is there something at least little similar around?

Comment: Have you tried [mockito](http://mockito.org/) (Java) or [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) (.NET)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is called an **Auto-Mocking Container**.

I'm not aware of any centralized, stable resource that defines the term, but just do a [web search for the term](http://www.google.com/search?q=auto-mocking%20container) and lots of articles are going to come up.

---

Update: I got tired of the lack of a proper pattern description, so [I wrote one](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container).